# C++ Unit Testing and stubbing a 3rd party C library

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googlemock

I need to unit test some C++ objects that I've written that use a 3rd party C library. For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I can't call the 3rd party C library directly, and need to stub it out for the test suite.

For other parts of our unit test suite we use `googlemock`, but I don't think it can be used for `C` libraries.  I can stub out the library manually, but prefer not to (partly due to laziness (its rather large), but mainly because its just a matter of principles).

So here's my question: is there a tool that generates stubbed code based on a `C` library header file? Once I have the stubbed-out code, I'll do some minor mods to it, then I'll link against it for the unit testing.

Comment: Intead of stubbing, why not wrap those C library function calls in classes as proposed in googlemock manual?

Comment: @matekm, I dont know googlemock that well, and will look into doing this. Im not sure about how this would work though, since my C++ objects call the C functions directly. Would I have to change the code to use Wrapper objects, and then use a mock of those objects for the unit testing?

Comment: look at http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions

Comment: @Brady: If you are not tied to googlemock, you can also take a look at HippoMocks(https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/hippomocks). It supports mocking of stand-alone functions without needing to rewrite the code that uses them.

Comment: Mocking is the wrong approach for substituting hard-to-test 3rd-party APIs. You don't care how your APIs get their job done and therefore any tests which scrutinise use of the 3rd-party lib will be brittle and will be testing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

[stubgen](http://www.radwin.org/michael/2011/05/10/stubgen/) can generate stub members from header files, unless you have special requirements it should be able to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried using stubgen for the C library header file, but it didnt generate anything. I think its only for C++ and not for C, as it mentions on the web page: "stubgen – a member function stub generator for C++"

Answer (score 2):

You cant wrap those calls in a class like described in http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Free_Functions

Then You can inject (in dynamic or static way) this class and set expectation on it.